# Bulma navbar hamburger menu doesn't expand

Tags: bulma, hamburger-menu

I copied [Bulma](https://bulma.io)'s [basic starter template](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/#starter-template) and the [basic navbar](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/#basic-navbar). However, when I click on the hamburger menu, nothing happens :(. Am I missing something? You can [try it in my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fprqwm5h/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Hello Bulma!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.4/css/bulma.min.css">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/js/all.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a class="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
            <img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" width="112" height="28">
          </a>

          <a role="button" class="navbar-burger burger" aria-label="menu" aria-expanded="false" data-target="navbarBasicExample">
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div id="navbarBasicExample" class="navbar-menu">
          <div class="navbar-start">
            <a class="navbar-item">
              Home
            </a>

            <a class="navbar-item">
              Documentation
            </a>

            <div class="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
              <a class="navbar-link">
                More
              </a>

              <div class="navbar-dropdown">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  About
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Jobs
                </a>
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Contact
                </a>
                <hr class="navbar-divider">
                <a class="navbar-item">
                  Report an issue
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="navbar-end">
            <div class="navbar-item">
              <div class="buttons">
                <a class="button is-primary">
                  <strong>Sign up</strong>
                </a>
                <a class="button is-light">
                  Log in
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
  <section class="section">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">
        Hello World
      </h1>
      <p class="subtitle">
        My first website with <strong>Bulma</strong>!
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/

"The Bulma package does not come with any JavaScript. 
Here is however an implementation example, which toggles the class is-active on both the navbar-burger and the targeted navbar-menu, in Vanilla Javascript."

add some js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

  // Check if there are any navbar burgers
  if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach( el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        const target = el.dataset.target;
        const $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        el.classList.toggle('is-active');
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

      });
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I'm surprised JavaScript is essentially required for this in a framework that is designed to not require JavaScript...